# Saving Date and Time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I don't know why the date and time is not saving on my Access Database. I follow some tutorial but it seems I'm having some problems on my code.

```
DateTime getdate = DateTime.Now;
String time = getdate.ToString("F");
```

and when I add

```
OleDbCommand cmdInsert = new OleDbCommand(@"insert into TblInventory (ItemCode,ProductName,Quantity,DateTime)
values ('" + txtItem.Text + "','" + txtProduct.Text + "','" + txtQuantity.Text + "','" + time +"')");
cmdInsert.Connection = con;
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Im stock. please help. thanks guys

The error says that there are problem on the `insert into statement`

Comment: show an example of the command in full once generated

Comment: What exactly is the error ? What is type of column ?

Comment: the program runs properly until I added date and time to be save. The date and time is in a ```text form``` in my database. Error says that there's a problem on my ```insert into statement```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name of your column is `DateTime` which is a keyword. You need to change name of column. Also use `Parameterized` query don't concatenate strings in query.

[List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx) of reserved words.

Comment: so it can be like this? (@"insert into TblInventory ([ItemCode],[ProductName],[Quantity],[DateTime])?

Comment: It can be but it is better to use parameterized SQl.